# how to align social media icons vertically on left side?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've created a simple social media icons with html and css.it is horizontally aligned on center of the page.  it should be arranged vertically on left side of the page. what i've to change here to do so?. i've to add these icons on my website. so it should fit on the left side

```css
    *{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "montserrat",sans-serif;
}

body{
  background: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


.social-buttons a{
  display: inline-flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 8px;
}

.social-buttons a::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,#a3a1a1,#0f0f0f);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
}

.social-buttons a:hover::before{
  transform: scale(0);
}

.social-buttons a i{
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
}

.social-buttons a:hover i{
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,#a3a1a1,#0f0f0f);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  transform: scale(2.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="social-buttons">
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-itch-io"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>

</body>
</html>
```

please help me to arrange these icons vertically on left side. waiting for response

Comment: Try the code that I have shared. It will work best in your case. It will not hinder your normal code flow. Do vote and accept the answer my friend :) Thanks

Comment: You are most welcome. Kindly also take a second or two to vote my answer and accept it my friend. This helps us stay motivated and use our time to help other's :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is to make a `position:absolute;` container for your icons. This  will not overlap with your normal code flow in your HTML You can work easily on the layout for rest of the code using this approach. Try the below code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css"
    />
  </head>

  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: "montserrat", sans-serif;
    }

    body {
      background: #fff;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }

    /* --- Add this CSS --- */
    .social-buttons {
      position: absolute;
      left: 1rem;
      top: 4rem;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .social-buttons a {
      display: inline-flex;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 18px;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      color: #fff;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
      margin: 4px 0;
    }

    .social-buttons a::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #a3a1a1, #0f0f0f);
      border-radius: 50%;
      z-index: -1;
      transition: 0.3s ease-in;
    }

    .social-buttons a:hover::before {
      transform: scale(0);
    }

    .social-buttons a i {
      transition: 0.3s ease-in;
    }

    .social-buttons a:hover i {
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #a3a1a1, #0f0f0f);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      transform: scale(2.2);
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="social-buttons">
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-itch-io"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `display:flex`; and `flex-direction: column;` to **.social-button** class and also remove `display:flex;` from body

```
.social-buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "montserrat", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.social-buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.social-buttons a {
  display: inline-flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px;
}

.social-buttons a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #a3a1a1, #0f0f0f);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
}

.social-buttons a:hover::before {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.social-buttons a i {
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
}

.social-buttons a:hover i {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #a3a1a1, #0f0f0f);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  transform: scale(2.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="social-buttons">
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-itch-io"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this if you want the icons to be horizontally aligned but it should appear on left side of the page then just remove **justify-content:center;** from body selector

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "montserrat",sans-serif;
}

body{
  background: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


.social-buttons a{
  display: inline-flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 8px;
}

.social-buttons a::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,#a3a1a1,#0f0f0f);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
}

.social-buttons a:hover::before{
  transform: scale(0);
}

.social-buttons a i{
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
}

.social-buttons a:hover i{
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,#a3a1a1,#0f0f0f);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  transform: scale(2.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="social-buttons">
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-itch-io"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>

</body>
</html>
```

OR if you need to align icons vertically and left aligned to the page then follow up the first Answer **Vikas Jadhav**